# How to do a branch per task strategy with git

Tags: git

Currently, my team is looking for an agile git branching strategy. I originally thought we could follow this article: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/, but unfortunately we do pushes to production too often to work on a branch with multiple tasks in it until it is stable (the next release branch strategy). Also, there is often situations where issues that should only take a few days to finish take a while to resolve due to priories changing. Because we do not have the time to work on these long running tasks they sit in dev or a next release branch and give way to the possibility of breaking production.

I want to adopt a branch per task strategy and want to know how it has been done with git before. I'm not just talking about feature branches, but a branch for every individual task you are assigned. Also, there would be no dev branch since your task branches will be your dev branch. Having a develop branch entices developers to commit directly to that branch which leads to open issues in our main branch.

I came up with this:

[image]

I believe adopting this strategy will keep the main branch clean and will also account for when developers are not around to finish their tasks before we do a push to production.

The main idea behind it is that the main branch is a protected branch and there is no development branch. Since the main branch is protected it will force you to create a branch off of it for individual tasks. In order to merge back in you have to request a merge from the administrator. We will tag every release to production and hotfixes will also be branches off of the main branch. We have four test sites set up that we can use to test the different task branches.

I haven't seen any examples of this strategy just yet, so I was hoping to get some feedback on what I have here.

**UPDATE**

So I know its been a while since this question was posted, but if anyone is looking for a similar strategy it seems that GitHub has adopted it [here](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/).

Comment: The diagram is unreadable. You should perhaps link it to a full-size version.

Comment: I am not linking to the image.

Comment: I am now* linking to the image.

Comment: the ProtectedMasterBranch.jpg image above is being blocked by my browser blocker because it says it's an "adult" site. Have you ever heard of Dropbox or Google? Something safe that some domainer isn't going to snatch up and turn into a porn site just to capitalize on the existing traffic?

Comment: The image is now 404.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The git flow model you mention is designed specifically to solve your problem :). Although it shows commits to `develop`, all tasks should be done in their own feature branch, and only merged back to `develop` once complete and tested. That way you know you can always release from `develop` (i.e. merge to master and tag), so it supports regular and continuous release.

Branch-per-task works really well with git flow because branching is cheap. We also use our issue numbers as prefixes, so `git flow feature start PR-123_make-widget` has a useable branch name but also highlights issue PR-123 in our JIRA.

Following the git-flow method as described above gives you a stable development branch (or maybe multiple stable development branches if you're working on a major new version branch as well as `develop`. You are also able to do hot-fixes which are applied directly to `master` and then merged back into `develop`.

For your 'request for merge', you could use pull requests (if you're using Github, Stash, Bitbucket, etc) or you could use a tool like Gerrit.

There's a reasonable argument that any branch which passes all tests should be merged back to develop automatically, in which case you could try doing per-commit micro reviews on feature branches. There are loads of options!

**Update** 
If you are going to persevere with your suggested model, I would recommend considering how your release cycle works. Does the release just involve tagging and pushing, or do you feature freeze for some time to carry out additional QA? Might you ever do that in the future? If the answer is 'yes' or 'maybe' then you shouldn't release from master, but should instead create a release branch, carry out your last minute fixes, and then tag and push. Don't forget to merge back as well though.

**Update**
If you are employing a branch-per-task strategy it might appear that the `master` branch serves no real purpose. If you are doing continuous release, so every stable develop branch build is deployed to your production environment automatically, this is probably true. In an environment where a build is promoted to production, without a release phase, i.e. the promotion doesn't involve any additional commits the additional branch is possibly unnecessary. The real benefit of the `develop`/`master` branching strategy comes when you have a release phase where final release fixes (deployment issues, last minute bugs, etc.) and general housekeeping such as version number bumps are done in a transient `release` branch.

Using the release branch and then merging that to a master branch means you can continue to merge stable features back into develop even though your release isn't complete yet.

It's also quite nice to have single commit points on the master branch, with each commit representing a release, but that's a purely aesthetic justification so isn't really that valid :).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions here :). At the moment we don't feature freeze, once an issue is fixed and tested we move it to production. I'm not sure if a feature freeze is something we are going to implement in the future, but is definitely something worth bringing up.

Comment: If we are employing a branch per task strategy doesn't that make the develop branch irrelevant? Keeping it there just adds an unnecessary step of having to merge your task branches back in. Also, having a develop branch entices developers to commit directly to that branch which leads to open issues in our main branch.

Comment: @ThePaxBisonica I've updated my answer to talk about master/develop branches.

Comment: We've got a similar problem to the OP -- customers submit requests to our cust svc dept; they post a ticket for us devs; we do the work in a folder specifically designated for that client (which persists over time); it could take an hour or a day or a week. When we're done, we send it out for review and approval by the client. We iterate until we get approval. Once we get approval, we push it into Master and also into Production. Personal opinions aside, this is what we do. Many customers have stuff they submit monthly for changes. It's all one-and-done.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to adopt a branch per task strategy and want to know how it has been done with git before

Git lightweight branching has been specifically designed with exactly this in mind, you can and ideally should create branches for each individual topic.

The following is quite subjective. The *successful branching model* that you refer to is successful because its plain common sense (and the marketing of calling it *successful* to reassure the world that branching and merging isn't scary at all). My own evidence is anecdotal, but it stands to reason that everyone who used git on a large enough project with many developers naturally had *release*, *develop*, *stage*, *featureX*, *featureY*, etc branches, or variants of thereof, with a common and normalised flow between them.

Your flow, as charted, makes sense, and one shoe doesn't fit all - you shouldn't be afraid to deviate from a *successful git branching model* where necessary!

Notwithstanding, with every such flow the main question is what's your staging, QA and release strategy. Fixing bugs, developing features, whether on topic branches or common branches isn't much of an issue, code is just code. And git is very good at moving code around between branches, splitting it to new branches, rewinding to code's old state, etc.

So what's more of an issue is how do you plan to QA and release the code. What are your resource limitations? (Build times, webservers, embedded harnesses, test farms, CI build and test boxes, etc.) Just as an example, if branching and moving code around is cheap, but building or re-building a branch takes 8 hours, then having a branch per a minuscule change doesn't make sense. Your flow has to consider this to be a successful one.

Comment: I'd definitely agree with the one shoe doesn't fit all comment. Although we have had immense success with the git flow model there are some use cases where it might be overkill or not solve the problem. When the author says "successful" they are merely saying it was successful for them and their use case. That said, if organisations such as Github and Atlassian are using it successfully, it's probably worth spending some time to understand *why* it's not working for you, and maybe improving your development processes before inventing a new solution

Comment: @spikeheap An [appeal to authority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_authority), don't you love them ... If Atlassian are using "it" successfully why exactly does the OP has to use it? Please explain the great comfort of relying on this fact.

Comment: I guess it's a good counter to [Not Invented Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here) right? The OP doesn't **have** to use it, but if you don't spend time to understand your reasons for choosing to implement it yourself you are taking time away from doing your real raison-d'etre: developing software. Also, companies like Atlassian are *generally* a beacon of good software development practice, and learning from others is how we develop!